# Cannot debug React Native android apps - permission denied for window type 2006

Tags: android, react-native

I've just change my `targetSdkVersion` to `26`. Before, I use `version 22`. 
When I try to run the app in debug mode, the app is always force closed.

On the Android studio, it shows error logs:

```
08-09 04:14:47.256 23321-23321/com.yummycorp.yummybox E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.yummycorp.yummybox, PID: 23321
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@4f2395d -- permission denied for window type 2006
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:789)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
    at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevLoadingViewController.setVisible(DevLoadingViewController.java:150)
    at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevLoadingViewController.access$100(DevLoadingViewController.java:39)
    at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevLoadingViewController$1.run(DevLoadingViewController.java:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Please can someone help me ? My React Native version is `0.47.2`
If you need more information, please ask me.

Thanks